# Will Cloud Computing ever cost me more than what I am getting from ad revenue?

Tags: android, performance, google-app-engine, admob, google-compute-engine

I made an app and it is a bit CPU intesive. So I want to delegate some of the work to cloud computing.

Hypothetically, if my only source of revenue is Admob ads, will there ever be a situation where I am paying, say $200 a month more than I am getting from ad revenue, on a pay-as-you-go plan? Or will I need funding at first or something?

I'm using this -> "Google Compute Engine"; pricing: https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing

Thank You.

Comment: fully dependsxon your specifics which arextoo broad to detail here. make a specific question about a specific *coding* issue

Comment: This isn't really a programming question and the answer depends on so many things: what resources your application consumes, how many ads you have, etc. You can model this in a spreadsheet to give you a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only emprical results can answer your question. There is no theory about your specific setup.

For a clue, I have a GAE webapp where the only source of income is adsense ads and the only cost is appengine hosting. This application runs at a profit now, but it didn't when volume was lower. So according to my experience there seems to be some "breaking point" going from low volume to medium when the app starts the become profitable.

If you ask whether your chances of monetizing your app has increased with cloud computing, then I'd definitely say the answer is yes.